# How can Peterson's algorithm possibly work without making unrealistic assumptions?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I don't get how software-only critical section algorithms like Peterson's and Lamport's can possibly work.

Wikipedia lists this pseudocode for Peterson's:

```
flag[me] = true;
turn  = other;
while (flag[other] == true && turn == 1)
     {
         // busy wait
     }
 // critical section
 // end of critical section
 flag[me] = false;
```

It seems to me like there's no way this could work in practice. What happens if the other thread of execution is far behind enough that `flag[other]` isn't even initialized?

For the bakery algorithm:

```
   Entering[i] = true;

  Number[i] = 1 + max(Number[1], ..., Number[NUM_THREADS]);

  Entering[i] = false;

  for (integer j = 1; j <= NUM_THREADS; j++) {

      // Wait until thread j receives its number:

      while (Entering[j]) { /* nothing */ }

      // Wait until all threads with smaller numbers or with the same

      // number, but with higher priority, finish their work:

      while ((Number[j] != 0) && ((Number[j], j) < (Number[i], i))) { /* nothing */ }

  }
```

What if one thread gets down into the for loop before the others have completed that initialization step above it? Am I missing something?

Wikipedia even says:

> The algorithm satisfies the three essential criteria to solve the
>   critical section problem, *provided that changes to the variables
>   turn, flag[0], and flag[1] propagate immediately and atomically*.

Isn't that an unreasonable assumption? It seems like these algorithms all assume some other means of synchronization so other threads don't perform operations in the middle of you doing your own operations, but if we already have that, isn't that all these algorithms are supposed to give you, for when you don't have hardware that can lock everyone else out for you, like the `LOCK` instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if the other thread of execution is far behind enough that flag[other] isn't even initialized?

You are correct: it is a requirement for Petersen's algorithm that the flags are initialized to zero.

> What if one thread gets down into the for loop before the others have completed that initialization step above it?

The [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm#Definitions) of the bakery algorithm say that the contents of the number array must start at 0.

> It seems like these algorithms all assume some other means of synchronization so other threads don't perform operations in the middle of you doing your own operations

In fact, the bakery algorithm is surprisingly free of these assumptions.  For example, the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm#Discussion) claims:

> Each thread only writes its own storage, only reads are shared. It is remarkable that this algorithm is not built on top of some lower level "atomic" operation, e.g. compare-and-swap. The original proof shows that for overlapping reads and writes to the same storage cell only the write must be correct. The read operation can return an arbitrary number. Therefore this algorithm can be used to implement mutual exclusion on memory that lacks synchronisation primitives, e.g., a simple SCSI disk shared between two computers.

It is true that they rely on the shared values starting with an initialized value, but in my experience this has never caused a problem.  For example, most multithreaded processes start as a single thread which forks the rest, so there are no problems providing all initialization is done statically or before the other threads are started.